# 'PCComm' is not a member of 'PCComm' error in Application.Designer.vb

Tags: .net, vb.net

I don't know why this error is occurring in an auto-generated file. Could anyone please look into it and help me out?

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On


Namespace My

    Partial Friend Class MyApplication

        <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>  _
        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New(Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationMode.Windows)
            Me.IsSingleInstance = false
            Me.EnableVisualStyles = true
            Me.SaveMySettingsOnExit = true
            Me.ShutDownStyle = Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.ShutdownMode.AfterMainFormCloses
        End Sub

        <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>  _
        Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
            Me.MainForm = Global.PCComm.PCComm.frmMain 'this is where the error occurs
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: does this `Global.PCComm.PCComm.frmMain` is in different project?

Comment: no, its all in one project @Claudius

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit the error line to read as:

```
Me.MainForm = Global.PCComm.frmMain
```

This worked for me.